# Show two TextViews inline across multiple lines

Tags: android, textview

I've ran into a bit of an issue as I'd like two TextViews to layout side-by-side even if the first TextView has several lines of text. Ideally, the next TextView should simply follow right after. It's a bit hard to explain, so I've made this picture to illustrate it:

[image]

*(the first TextView contains a title, and the second TextView contains a year)*

I've been trying a few different things now, both layout hacks and using Html.fromHtml(), but nothing has worked so far. It's probably impossible to do, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: It helps if we can see some code

Comment: @Michell Bak : Why don't you just append the year to the title?

Comment: @azulflame Not really. It's a simple LinearLayout with two nested TextViews.

Comment: @Squonk I want it to stand out from the title.

Comment: You can simply use a smaller font size, Spannable, etc for the year: [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1529068/1267661)

Comment: @MichellBak : Also have a look at this site which explains Spannable text http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Comment: I think Spannable might be the way to go, yeah. Thanks, I'll have a look :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `Spannable`.  As you've noticed the problem with doing two views is that the bounds of the `TextView` in your two line example is still a rectangle, so laying out the second view at the end of the text gets tricky.  HTML can work for simple tags (bold, underline, headings), but isn't too flexible.

The solution is to use `Spannable` to create the text ouf of pieces of content with specific formatting applied to each "span".  As it turns out, then you can just stick the whole results right into a single `TextView`.  Something like:

```
TextView tv; //Defined somewhere else

SpannableStringBuilder resultBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
SpannableString item = new SpannableString("Long and Fancy Movie Title Here");
item.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(18, true), 0, item.length(), 0);
resultBuilder.append(item);

SpannableString item = new SpannableString("(2011)");
item.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(12, true), 0, item.length(), 0);
resultBuilder.append(item);

tv.setText(resultBuilder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

There are a ton of different span definitions in `android.text.style`, the above is just an example to create two different text sizes in the same string.  You should be able to get what you want out of this one, `TextAppearanceSpan`, `TypefaceSpan`, or some other combination.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Two side by side TextView in a RelativeLayout might do the trick, I don't see why the Html.fromHtml wont work if you add the right html formatting

Comment: A RelativeLayout doesn't work. It'll move the second TextView to the right of the first TextView. That can leave a huge gap between the first and second, if the first has more than one line of text.

As for `Html.fromHtml()` I was using `<small>(2011)</small>` for the second part, and it completely dismissed the `small`-tag.

Comment: This might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at that, but like I said I couldn't get the `small`-tag to work.

Comment: Strange, I was following this guide http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Do you suppose it could be device related, have you tried on another device?

Comment: another possible workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize

Comment: Spannable seems to get the job done, and Devunwired posted a complete solution, so I'm accepting that, but +1 for your comments as well!