# Changing text within textview

Tags: android, textview

So is it possible to change text size of part of the text in textview dynamically
Let's say we have a method that does that...what am I missing...I want to make x variable twice as big as y...they are string btw...

```
private void Data_transfer() {

    test3.setText( x + "   " + y);
    }
```

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Spannable` type with a `TextView` to set [multiple styles in one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview).

In your case, you can do this like so, using the [`fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) method which generates a `Spannable` string:

```
test3.setText( Html.fromHtml( "<font size='10'>" + x + "</font>   <font size='5'>" + y + "</font>" ) );
```

And you can, of course, change `10` and `5` to whatever values you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Data_transfer() {

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Welcome to android");

}
```

Comment: Ok I know that part but what if your text consists of 3 variables: a,b,c ..a = Welcome, b = to, c = android...and I want different sizes for every each of them...what then?