# Multiple textsize in a single textview in android

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to set different `TextSize` for different parts of the content of a given `Textview` using XML in android ?

Comment: You can do that in java code. Misread the question at first and posted a alternative solution

Comment: through xml, I don't think it's possible. But in Java code you can achieve it using Html tags or through `SpannableString`.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "...using XML in android ?" mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible from the XML, but you can do it in JAVA.

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize).

Answer (score 2):

Programatically but not using XML you could achieve it using `setSpan`

For 10 Characters word with first 5 chars has fontsize 12 and last 5 chars has 16.

```
 Textview myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); SpannableString
 text = new SpannableString(myString);

 text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 12, null, null),0,5,
 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 

 text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 16, null, null),6,10,
 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 myTextView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```