# How to increase font size in strings.xml in android

Tags: android, string

I have string which should look like below

```
 <string name="text">
    <![CDATA[Text in bigger font size 20.. Text in normal font size 10
        ]]>
    </string>
```

Any idea or inputs whether this can be achievable? It is preferable if I use  CDATA tag, but unfortunately the font tag isn't working inside the CDATA. The font through the text remains the same even if I set the size..
I will consume this string in a TextView.

Answer (score 24):

```
<string name="text">
    <font size="20">Text in bigger font size 20..</font><font size="10"> Text in normal font size 10</font> 
</string>
```

Comment: what if text is wrapped with double quotes for escaping apostrophes?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has been here for so long but seems like there is no proper answer.

In your strings.xml file you put

```
<string name="text">
<![CDATA[<font size="20">Text in bigger font size 20.. </font><font size="10">Text in normal font size 10</font>]]> </string>
```

And in your java code file
put this line

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources.getString(R.string.text)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are strings and a TextView is a visual tool to display a string.

You should put the text size in the TextView definition in the XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Or in the code

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextSize(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:textSize`  in the `TextView` tag inside your layout file

eg:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#ff1917ff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a span to change font size of a portion of text.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize) answer for span code.

In your case you can set size to 10 and span with double the size for the first portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside :-

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```