# textViews with same textsize but show different in textsize,why

Tags: android

this is the preview
[this is the preview links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjJFW.png)
and my layout code is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.asop.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="这是一段测试文字"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<com.asop.MixedTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:text1="这是一段测试文字"
    app:text1size="20sp" />
```

as you see,here is two textView with same text and same textSize,but it shows different in textsize,l dont understand why,who can give me a explain,thank.if
there is errors in MixedTextView ,please give me the right code thanks.
below is the code of MixedTextView

```
public class MixedTextView extends LinearLayout {
private static final int TEXTSIZE = 16;
private static final int TEXTCOLOR = R.color.normal;
private static final int DEVIDER_LENGTH = 5;
private String text1;
private String text2;
private int text1Color;
private int text2Color;
private int text1Size;
private int text2Size;
private int deviderLength;
private TextView tv1, tv2;

public MixedTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MixedTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MixedTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MixedTextView);
    text1 = ta.getString(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text1);
    text2 = ta.getString(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text2);
    text1Size = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text1size, TEXTSIZE);
    text2Size = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text2size, TEXTSIZE);
    text1Color = ta.getColor(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text1color, getResources().getColor(TEXTCOLOR));
    text2Color = ta.getColor(R.styleable.MixedTextView_text2color, getResources().getColor(TEXTCOLOR));
    deviderLength = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MixedTextView_deviderLength, DEVIDER_LENGTH);
    ta.recycle();
    initView(context);
}

private void initView(Context context) {
    tv1 = new TextView(context);
    tv1.setSingleLine();
    tv1.setText(text1);
    tv1.setTextSize(text1Size);
    tv1.setTextColor(text1Color);

    tv2 = new TextView(context);
    tv2.setSingleLine();
    tv2.setText(text2);
    tv2.setTextSize(text2Size);
    tv2.setTextColor(text2Color);

    View devider = new View(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams deviderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(deviderLength, 1);
    if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL)
        deviderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1, deviderLength);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    addView(tv1, layoutParams);
    addView(devider, deviderParams);
    addView(tv2, layoutParams);
}
<declare-styleable name="MixedTextView">
    <attr name="text2" format="string" />
    <attr name="text1" format="string" />
    <attr name="text1color" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="text2color" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="text1size" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="text2size" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="deviderLength" format="dimension|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: You have use CustomTextView (MixedTextView) for second text.

Comment: Why is your MixedTextView extending LinearLayout? According to me a TextView extends View, change that and run your code again.

Comment: If you world like to shown same text then use same TextView  either MixedTextView or TextView.

Comment: may be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize?rq=1

Comment: The `setTextSize()` method expects the argument to be in scaled pixels (`sp`), but you're passing straight pixels. Change the `setTextSize()` calls to `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size)`.

Comment: in fact,your explain is right,you are so good,thanks @ Mike M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified by practice,the correct answer is in comment list 5:
The setTextSize() method expects the argument to be in scaled pixels (sp), but l passed straight pixels. so here l need to
Change the setTextSize() calls to setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size) in MixedTextView, thanks  @[Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)

Answer (score -1):

The reason is your text style or font style for both the text is different.The one is **TextView** and the other one is **com.asop.MixedTextView**. I hope you get my point.

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: ok ..but i dont know why folks downvote if the answer is right.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but your answer is essentially "they're different because they're different things". That might be technically correct, but it doesn't really help the OP.