# How to view two different textview in one line but seems to the user as one textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I have two [textview](/questions/tagged/textview)s different in font and style I need to put them in one line but seems to the user one [textview](/questions/tagged/textview).
more details if the 2nd text is big from the screen I need it to be completed in the second line under the first text.
ex-1: **text1** text2
ex-2: **teeeeeext1** teeeeee
    eeeext2
I don't know if it possible to do that or not so I asked for help.
**[Edit]**
it's important to make them in two [textview](/questions/tagged/textview)s because I'll set two different click listeners to them.
thanks.

Comment: you can use LinearLayout put both the text view in linearlayout, and make orientation horizontal

Comment: @PramodYadav but this way will make the 2nd textview will be completed under its side, I need it to be completed under the 1st textview from the start of the line.

Comment: @Tefa it is completely possible to add two textviews side by side, But if you want to send the text of second textview under first then it won't be possible the way you are asking. Because if that text goes into second line it will be it's area, not under the first one.

Comment: @Umair yes, this is the problem I faced so I tried to get any Idea.

Comment: @Tefa what have you tried so far can i see some code so i will be able to help you more ? And secondly I can give you the example how to show the textview side by side but showing the text in second line you have to come up with something else :)

Comment: @Tefa  Please check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388398/1518273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this custom span class I wrote with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697453/2940733) and android's `StyleSpan` class.

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by aminmsvi on 9/7/2017
 */
public class CustomClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    private final int mStyle;
    private final ClickableSpanListener mListener;

    /**
     * @param style An integer constant describing the style for this span. Examples
     *              include bold, italic, and normal. Values are constants defined
     *              in {@link android.graphics.Typeface}.
     */
    public CustomClickableSpan(@Nullable ClickableSpanListener listener, int style) {
        mStyle = style;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Copied this method from {@link android.text.style.StyleSpan} source code
     */
    private static void apply(Paint paint, int style) {
        int oldStyle;

        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int want = oldStyle | style;

        Typeface tf;
        if (old == null) {
            tf = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(want);
        } else {
            tf = Typeface.create(old, want);
        }

        int fake = want & ~tf.getStyle();

        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onClick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
         apply(ds, mStyle);
    }

    public interface ClickableSpanListener {

        void onClick();
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("This is a text");
        spannableString.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "This is a text".substring(0, 4), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, 0);
        spannableString.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "This is a text".substring(5, 10), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), Typeface.ITALIC), 5, 10, 0);
        textView.setText(spannableString);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        // if you want to remove highlight color, uncomment this line
        // textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If u want u can use `fromHtml` tag so that both font and style in one textview only..that would satisfy the need of text coming in next line too

Comment: I forget to add that I need to add different click listeners to each one.

Comment: u can try by adding two transparent views over the text..n check which text is in one line ..bring the view of text which have 1 line by bringToFront(). And handling clicks on the views rather then `textview`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using SpannableStringBuilder Class and I guess this  is the answer you are searching for [SpannableStringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405694/6007359)

Comment: It will work if didn't need to add a click listener to each one, but unfortunately, I need to add a click listener to each one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show two textview's side by the without giving user the idea that it's a single thing then try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horzontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="TextView asdasdasd as das dasdasdas adasd asdas d" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I need it to be a single thing.

Comment: @Tefa if you need two click listeners then you need two textviews. ;) and secondly when you make your layout like this then these widgets will seems to be in the same line or a single thing.